# Form element directive with error message manage AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, directive

I'm trying to create a input directive element with validation.
I'd like to manage error status in this directive.

There are 3 files

- Index.html:  uses this directive
- textValid.js:  contains directive code
- textValid.html: contains the directive template

I create this directive

**textValid.js**

```
App.directive("textValid", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "tpl/textValid.html",
        require: "?ngModel",

        scope: {
            name: "@",
            element: "=",
            model: "="
        }
    };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<form name="edit_form_ctrl.contract_edit_form" action="#" novalidate >
     <div class="row">
         <text-valid name="ncontract"model="edit_form_ctrl.contract.ncontract"
                     element="edit_form_ctrl.contract_edit_form.ncontract">
         </text-valid>
     </div>
</form>
```

and template **textValid.html**

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="model" class="form-control" ng-required="true" value="{{model}}" />
     <div>pristine: {{element.$pristine}}</div> <!--is always undefined-->
     <div>Invalid: {{element.$error}}</div> <!--is always undefined-->
<span class="color-red" ng-if="element.$error.required  &&!element.$pristine">
    {{curLang.field_mandatory}}
</span>
```

I'm trying to get input control to check $error and $pristine value, but I cannot to achieve it.

I read all documentation and the book too, but with any results.

Does someone try to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add {{double-curlies}} around the name attribute of the input element like so:

```
<input type="text" name="{{name}}" ng-model="model" class="form-control" ng-required="true" />
```

You should be able to access the [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) for it from inside `text-valid` with `$scope.form[$scope.name]`

A couple other notes:

1. using a `value` attribute on and element with `ng-model` attribute will not have an effect.
2. you have `require: '?ngModel'` in your directive definition, but there is no `ng-model` attribute on the `text-valid` element.  This is ok, but you won't get any `ngModelController` being injected unless the `text-valid` element has an `ng-model` attribute.

**Edit:**

Because `text-valid` has isolate scope, to access the `FormController`, you would need to require it and bind it:

```
App.directive("textValid", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "tpl/textValid.html",
        require: "^^form",

        scope: {
            name: "@",
            element: "=",
            model: "="
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attr, FormCtrl){
            $scope.form = FormCtrl;
            // now you should be able to access $scope.form[$scope.name]
            // (you *might* need to put any initialization that accesses it inside a $timeout to wait for it to be rendered/bound)
        }
    };
});
```

In template, you should then be able to access it like:

```
<div>pristine: {{form[name].$pristine}}</div>
<div>Invalid: {{form[name].$error}}</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean in link function within directive? I tried to add in textValid.js link: function($scope, element, attr, ctrl) but $scope.form[name] return a error  'cos form is null.

Comment: ah right, text-valid has isolate scope.  I've edited my answer with consideration of this.

Comment: Thanks man! It works.... Just a question: what means these two '^^'  before form?!

Comment: Glad that it works!  `^^` in the require means require from the DOM element's ancestor.  `^` in require means require from the DOM element OR an ancestor.  Check [Comprehensive Directive API docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) under **require** in the **Directive Definition Object** section

Comment: Thank you for all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="model" class="form-control" ng-required="true" value="{{model}}" />
     <div>pristine: {{form.name.$pristine}}</div> <!--is always undefined-->
     <div>Invalid: {{form.name.$error}}</div> <!--is always undefined-->
<span class="color-red" ng-if="element.$error.required  &&!element.$pristine">
    {{curLang.field_mandatory}}
</span>
```

Comment: this would technically work, but wouldn't really allow re-use of the `text-valid` directive in a form because there would be multiple inputs named `'name'`

Comment: You're right... I was wrong. {{name}} is the correct value. So it can be dynamic